# How to output a string in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am a new comer to AS3, and I want to output a string to see its value, just like printf of C or cout of C++. Below is the code. I want to see the result of compressing string "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", and I tried trace(), but when I run it, nothing appeared on my browser. Please help me, thanks!!!

```
public class StringCompress extends Sprite
{
    public function StringCompress()
    {
        var beforeCompressStr:String ="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        var afterCompressStr:String = Compress(beforeCompressStr);
        trace(afterCompressStr);
    }
            ...
}
```

Comment: you will not see output in your browser, `trace` works only inside flash IDE `press F2` to see the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get a trace output on the browser without the help of a 3rd party plugin.

You can install flashbug :

http://blog.coursevector.com/flashbug

So as to get the trace output there.

Comment: Great thanks! I the IDE is use is Adobe Flash Builder, can flash bug also be integrated with it? And how?

Comment: Also, your browser has to have the debugger version of Flash Player installed.  You can get this from Adobe.  And you have to have tracing output turned on when you create the SWF file.  And you have to read the docs on how to set and use the debugging environment that Flash Builder provides.  :)

Comment: seems a bit complicated. I just want to print out a string variable, is there any alternative solution in AS3?

Comment: Adobe Flash Builder is based on Eclipse. Instead of "Run" click "Debug". And it will output the value in output window.

Comment: add a `TextField` to the stage and write your debugging info to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep using trace() but make sure to debug instead of just run your program so the trace statements can show up in Flash Builder.